# Difference between science fiction/fantasy and futurism according to Philip K. Dick

Tags: blade-runner, philip-k-dick, blade-runner-series

In [this letter from Philip K. Dick to The Ladd Company](http://archive.is/z2HU), he references a Harrison Ford interview where he says that that Blade Runner is not fantasy nor science fiction, but futurism.

What's did he mean by that? What else would fit into this genre?

Comment: I can't speak for him, but it seems to me that he just wanted to say that Blade Runner is a piece of art and not just another sci-fi movie made after yet another pulp story. It's clear from the letter that he was amazed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fiction that is based on hard science and attempts to make real predictions about the future based on science and the scientific method is often called "Futurism", or "Speculative Fiction", or just "Hard Sci-fi".   Asimov, Clarke, Frederik Pohl, and Poul Anderson have published examples of this.

In the case of Blade Runner, the novel's title was the thesis topic: "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?", and PKD attempted to explore the realities of what a convincing synthetic human would be like.

Comment: No, he means Frederick Pohl: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Pohl

Comment: Not all of Asimov is hard sci-fi. The psionic abilities that are mentioned in the later parts of the Foundation books fall entirely outside of any conceivable definition for hard SF.

Comment: @GoranJovic I'm pretty sure that the copy of a magazine I had in the 80's spelled both men's names Pohl.  I didn't realize the error, thanks!

Comment: @Donald.McLean argument from personal astonishment,  because you don't find it scientifically plausable it must not be?  If we're going to throw out stories with suppositions that aren't well supported most hard SF goes out the window:  The Heechee figured out how to survive the crushing gravity inside of an event horizon.  Probably not the best sceince.  Clarke absolutely implied that the aliens in 2001 and also in Rendezvous with Rama had psychic powers.

Comment: And just so we're clear - Poul Anderson didn't even stick to SF, let alone hard SF. See Three Hearts and Three Lions.

Comment: I'm not saying that psionics can't be science fiction, only that they can't be HARD SF. Hard SF is strictly limited to what we currently understand is reasonably possible - no psionics, no FTL, no time travel. Yes, it is severely limited - that's why it is considered both difficult and interesting.

Comment: @Donald.McLean I didn't intend to say that all of Anderson was hard SF.  As for your assertions that all of those things are impossible, how much physics have you taken?  I can posit scenarios where FTL is possible, also time travel.  You seem like one of those people who insist that everything in the universe has to be reproducable and ordered or it never happened.  As for psionics it's easily in the realm of science... We can talk about that somewhere else if you want. Note that I removed the word "ALL". :)

Comment: Not "possible" as in "we might discover how to do this" but possible as in "with enough money we could do it now with our current scientific knowledge".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3146/discussion-between-nathan-c-tresch-and-donald-mclean)

Comment: I don't know about speculative, I'm talking strictly about hard SF. Hard SF can contain things that have not been invented yet, but everything - including new inventions - must be based on science as we currently understand it. For example, there are "theories" for FTL, but none of them are widely accepted or even worked out in enough detail that we might conceivably build an FTL ship. And psionics are generally NOT accepted by the scientific community.

Comment: Can whomever downvoted let me know why?

Comment: For some reason this topic bubbled to the top of the heap. I wanted to take minor issue with the idea that PKD was exploring androids, but rather he went on record saying the android concept was used to rather explore the idea of humans without empathy. He read a lot of Nazi materials esp. during work on *Man in The High Castle* and he explicitly mentions a diary entry of an SS officer as the impetus for the train of thought.

Comment: Regardless of what PKD himself thought, I've read almost everything by him (I'm a complete fan) and I don't think he wrote _hard_ SF. Like an introduction to his short story collection states, PKD wasn't a scientifically minded individual. What he explored was the _psychology_ of humankind (or the "technology of the soul", as one reviewer aptly puts it), through fantastic visions of the present and future. Little in his stories feels realistic; they are mostly an exploration of what it means to be human, but in "weird fiction" and bizarre situations. That's my take, anyway...

Comment: @Donald.McLean I'd say of the writers mentioned in this article, only Clarke can be considered to have written "hard" SF (and not always). Asimov sometimes, but much of what he wrote was _soft_ SF. PKD only wrote soft SF (in my opinion, of course). This isn't a quality judgment, btw: I absolutely _love_ PKD and don't consider his soft SF any lesser than Clarke's hard SF.